# RxJava: turn a callback into an Observable without changing

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I'm kinda new to RxJava, but I'm trying to learn it. In this case however I have a code which I cannot change, which uses a simple callback model. But the callback isn't called directly and I cannot parameterize it, but I still would like to use Observables. The basic example is, I'd call myFunc() which returns an observable and start a background operation. Then that background operation would return in myCallback. WHat I want is to then call onNext with the result THEN I could do something with the result. I'm just not sure what to use, is this something to do with Subjects?

```
private void doStuff() {
    myFunc().subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object o) {
            System.out.println("DO SOMETHING WITH THE RESULT");
        }
    });
}

private void myCallback(Object result) {
    [SOMETHING].onNext(result);
}

private Observable<Object> myFunc() {
    //Do stuff which will return in myCallback
    return [SOMETHING]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `PublishSubject`:

```
PublishSubject<T> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject
   // run in background
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) 
  .doOnNext(item -> doSomething(item))
  //make sure you log errors somewhere!
  .subscribe(subscriber);
```

After subscription is established:

```
subject.onNext(item1);
subject.onNext(item2);
subject.onCompleted();
```

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the meantime, but yeah I did the same :)